# ActionBar Styling not working

Tags: android

I am used  Jeff Gilfelt actionbar generator to generate actionbar style for my app. I modified the manifest file to reflect the new theme i downloaded and put in my resource but it's still not working. What could possibly be wrong.

Here is my styles file

```
<style name="Theme.Hope" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_hope</item>
  <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Hope</item>
  <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Hope</item>
  <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Hope</item>
  <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Hope</item>
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Hope</item>
  <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_hope</item>
  <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_hope</item>
  <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Hope</item>
</style>
```

Here is my manifest

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.Hope" >
```

Comment: this theme is present for versions i think above 11 .. does ur device support actionbar ?? or u might need to change that to sherlock actionbar or actionbar compat in that case.